# What to do with a question that has only received comments

Tags: discussion, comments, unanswered-questions, answers-as-comments

I have recently made a post on one of the other groups that I follow. I received a bunch of comments, and a few that actually solved my problem, but no answer to close off the question.

**Question**
What should I do with this question?

Should I **remove** my question and assume it was too trivial (as it was a quick fix), or **leave it up** even though I have not officially received an answer at this time?

ALSO

What is the protocol on this kind of thing should it happen again in the future?

Do I wait a short period of time and just remove it if no official answer comes in (assuming that the problem was small, or that I probably needed to revise it)?

Comment: After waiting a short period of time I, as the OP, would post an answer quoting the comments, mark it as accepted and mark it as a community wiki.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will depend upon the particular question and comments but when I see an unanswered question that seems to have been adequately answered in comments I will sometimes write an answer that:

- starts by saying "As per comments by @...:"
- quotes the relevant comments
- adds any extra value that I can to the answer

I think this approach becomes more valid as more time passes since the comment trail ceased being added to, and is just as valid for a self-answer as it is for answering someone else's question.

A recent example where I have done this is: [Repeating points by field using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156982/repeating-points-by-field-using-arcgis-for-desktop)

Comment: I'm a little sad that this question was properly answered.